# IOS How to achive a view in the headerView fixed in the navigation bar position?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Tableview How to do slide up to the navigation bar, a view in the headerView  fixed in the navigation bar position, the cell below can continue to slide up. Similar to the address book effect, but with the address book is not the same

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom headerview to the section as you like ,as far as i know the headerview will not scroll along with the tableview.(FYI should work for tableview with multiple section)
If not use a uiview and put it in the top of the tableview.So while you scroll the tableview will only scroll and the uiview will remain at the same position.

Comment: Thank you 我的意思是在headView中，而不是tableHeaderView。